# Show that $SO(3)$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In the following we identify $n \times n$ matrices with the space $R^{n^2}$
by sending entries in the first column to the first $n$ coordinates, those in the 2nd column to next $n$ coordinates, and so on. Let $O(3)$ be the set of orthogonal matrices. Let $SO(3)$ be the subset of $O(3)$ such that $\det(A)=1$ for any $A \in SO(3)$.

I started by showing that $O(3)$ is compact by showing that is closed and bounded in the metric space. Any hints on how to proceed from here?
�

Comment: What are the equations defining $SO(3)$, as a subset of $R^9$? What about as a subset of $O(3)$?

Comment: SO(3) is a set of orthogonal $3x3$ matrices where the determinant is equal to 1.

Comment: And the determinant is a continuous function in the entries of the matrix, right?

Comment: Yes. In addition, the image of a compact map under a continuous map is compact. So is SO(3) compact because you can define f as a determinant mapping from O(3) to SO(3) and because a determinant is a continuous function.

Comment: But  the preimage  of a compact  set under a continuous  map may be not compact.

Answer (score 9):

You showed that $O(3)$ is compact.  Now $SO(3)$ is a subset of that compact set as well as the preimage of the closed set $\{1\}$ under the continuous function  $\det$, hence closed itself.  We know that closed subsets of compact spaces are compact as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is closed and bounded in $L(\mathbb{R}^3)$.  Since all norms are equivalent on a finite dimensional normed space, it is compact.

Comment: What is $L(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

Comment: The linear transformations on $\mathbb{R^3}$.