# Show that SO(3) is an embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3} \equiv M(3,n)$ without using Regular Level Set Theorem

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

This question was asked in my assignment of Smooth manifolds course and I am struct on this problem.

> Show that $SO(3) =${$ A\in M(3,n) |A^T A=I , det A= 1$ } is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I found a solution while searching this website: [Show that $SO(3)$ in an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944378/show-that-so3-in-an-embedded-submanifold-of-mathbbr3-times-3).

but this solution uses Regular Level Set Theorem which has not been covered in my course.

I tried by using the definition of Submanifold which is: I have to show that SO(3) is a k-dimensional submanifold of M(3,n) : If $P\in SO(3) $ P being a point, there is a chart $(U, \phi)$ containing P such that $\phi(U \cap  SO(3,n))$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^9$.

Here $U\subseteq  SO(3)$ . But I am not able to move foreward from here.

Kindly help me!

Comment: There is something to fix in the question as for $n \neq 3$, $\det A$ is not defined.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I typed the question as it was in assignment. Can you please elaborate on why exactly for $n\neq 3$ it is not defined?

Comment: The determinant is only defined for square matrices.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net What edit in statement of  my question should I do so that this question can be solved?  Can you please tell?

Comment: @Avenger This is about $M(3,n)$. Usually this means the set of matrices with $3$ lines and $n$ columns (more frequently noted $M_{3,n}(\mathbb{R})$). This is the reason of the remark "for $n \ne 3$, $\det A$ is not defined". Same remark for $SO(3,n)$: you probably mean $SO(3)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556412/show-that-so3-is-compact

Comment: How do we embed $SO(2)$ in $\Bbb{R}^4$?

Comment: Is $M(3,n)$ supposed to be $M(3,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Also, $SO(3)$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so something is wrong with your question.

Comment: @Randall I typed the same as it is in assignment.

Comment: @BobDobbs I am sorry but I don't know how to do it.  I am a beginner in this.

Comment: @Avenger There is an obvious embedding $SO(3)\subset M(3,\Bbb{R})=\Bbb{R}^9$...

Comment: We are all beginners. Each day. @Avenger

Comment: But your title question and the highlighted problem in the question body are different.

Answer (score 1):

Jean Gallier's notes: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/gma-v2-chap5.pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ejean/gma-v2-chap5.pdf) See Page 55/ Question 5.4.(ii).

Let $V_3:S^3\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^{10}$ be the Veronese map $V_3(x,y,z,t)=(x^2,y^2,z^2,t^2,xy, xz, xt, yz, yt, zt)$. Then, since $V_3(-x,-y,-z,-t)=V_3(x,y,z,t)$ it induces an embedding $\phi: \Bbb{P}^3\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{10}$ such that $V_3=\phi\circ\pi$ where $\pi: S^3\rightarrow\Bbb{P}^3$ is the quotient map. On the other hand, the image of $V_3$ is into the hyperplane $H\subset\Bbb{R}^{10}$ defined by the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1$. Since $H\cong\Bbb{R}^{9}$, we have an embedding $\psi: SO_3\cong\Bbb{P}^3\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{9}$. But, I don't know how to make this map more explicit. Also, this is an algebraic geometric approach. I am trying to find an algebraic topologic approach which uses the canonical line bundle of the projective space.

We have also the obvious embedding $SO(3)\subset M(3,\Bbb{R})=\Bbb{R}^9$.

$SO(3)=\Bbb{P}^3$ can not be embedded in $\Bbb{R}^4$ but it embedds in $\Bbb{R}^5$. To do this embedd the projective plane $\Bbb{P}^2$ in $\Bbb{R}^4$, then choose a point $x_0\in\Bbb{R}^5$ which is not in $\Bbb{R}^4\subset\Bbb{R}^5$. Then, construct the cone with base $\Bbb{P}^2$ and apex $x_0$. This cone is $SO(3)$ (?).

Comment: Hi! Can you please prove how the embedding $\phi$ is induced ( I am talking about 4th line of your answer)? $\phi : \mathbb{P}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^{10}$ ? Which result you used? I shall be grateful if you can elaborate on this!

Comment: $\pi:S^3\rightarrow\Bbb{P}^3$ is a $2:1$ covering projection. It is an an open map. The continuity of $\phi$ follows from these. Doesn't it?

Comment: Image of $\phi$ is  into $H$ because $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1$.

Comment: When is a map 2:1 covering projection? Can you please tell what is the definition?

Comment: Covering projections are local homeomorphisms. But globally they are not. They are $n:1$, onto maps, $n>1$. $n$ can be $\infty$. For example, $\pi:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$, $\pi(x)=exp(2\pi i x)$, is an $\infty :1$ covering projection. Here , there is two important covering projections: $q : S^3\rightarrow SO(3)$ is a $2:1$ covering projection and it is related to the quaternion numbers we almost never use them in mathematics. The other is $\pi : S^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{P}^3$ which is $2:1$ again. We can draw neither $S^3$ nor projective space.